# Concurrent polling downstream dependencies and wait until all of them succeed

Tags: java, concurrency

I am trying to write a simple function that long-polls multiple messages tothe downstream dependency without exhausting it and only exist when all messages succeeded.

I came up with a way to wrap each message polling into a callable and use a ExecutorService to submit a list of callables.

```
    public void poll(final List<Long> messageIdList) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(messageIdList.size());
        List<MessageStatusCallable> callables = messageIdList.stream()
                .map(messageId -> new MessageStatusCallable(messageId)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        boolean allSuccess = false;
        try {
            allSuccess = executorService.invokeAll(callables).stream().allMatch(success -> {
                try {
                    return success.get().equals(Boolean.TRUE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class MessageStatusCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
        private Long messageId;
        public MessageStatusCallable(Long messageId) {
            this.messageId = messageId;
        }

        /**
         * Computes a result, or throws an exception if unable to do so.
         *
         * @return computed result
         * @throws Exception if unable to compute a result
         */
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            String messageStatus = downstreamService.getMessageStatus(messageId);
            while(messageStatus == null || !messageStatus.equals( STATUS_VALUE_SUCCEEDED) {
                messageStatus = messageLogToControlServer.getMessageStatus(messageId);
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toMillis(100));
            }
            LOG.info("Message: " + messageId + " Succeded");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this since Thread.sleep is blocking and ugly.

Comment: You don't need  to poll. Just call `Future.get()` on al the `Futures`, in any order. When you get them all you're done.

Comment: @user207421 do u mean I don't need to do a while loop to poll the downstream service?

Comment: No, I mean what I said: you don't need to poll, let alone a while loop. All you're doing is waiting for them all to end, so just do that.

Comment: @user207421 sorry I didn't get your point. If I don't poll, how do I know when to stop? A message could take 1 seconds to be succeeded but it could also take half an hour

Comment: If your point means not polling but just wait for a fixed time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but it occurred to me you could use a `CountDownLatch` and `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
    public void poll(final List<Long> messageIdList) throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(messageIdList.size());
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
        try {
            for (Long messageId : messageIdList) {
                MessageStatusCallable callable = new MessageStatusCallable(messageId, latch);
                executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                        () -> {
                            String messageStatus = downstreamService.getMessageStatus(messageId);
                            if (STATUS_VALUE_SUCCEEDED.equals(messageStatus)) {
                                latch.countDown();
                                throw new CompletionException("Success - killing the task", null);
                            }
                        }, 
                        0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }

            latch.await();

        } finally {
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

I probably also wouldn't have the Runnable as a lambda other than for brevity in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Marc, it's a much better solution than mine. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to close a single task? Since I saw u use CompletionException to close one polling task

Comment: I suppose you could have a map of message ids and scheduled futures and then call cancel on the scheduled future or if you extract the task back out into a class you could pass in a callback to the task and that callback could decrement the latch and cancel the task.

Comment: I would also consider reworking it so poll doesn't block but the callback calls the code to continue processing after all the messages have been retrieved. You would have to either raise the scope of the executor or shut it down from the callback though.